# Static Bootstrap page as a front page in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I've got 2 separate running websites:

1. Static bootstrap html website
2. Wordpress blog (GoDaddy.com domain and Wordpress package, example.com)

---

What I would like to do is to have these two websites on one domain.

For example, the 1st page (Bootstrap static) as a front page at example.com and then the Wordpress blog at example.com/blog.

What is the best and easiest way to do that? Do I really need to transform static html page into php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just follow two steps without any complications:

1. Install the WordPress software inside root/blog ( eg: `public_html/site_folder/blog`)
2. Upload the Bootstrap HTML(index.html) in your root folder ( eg: `public_html/site_folder/index.html`)

In this way these two operate separately, both will not interfere with each others functionalities.